# Model is working fine in one view, but throwing an exception in another one

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm learning asp .net and trying to build something similar to an online library. I have a Book Model class and I'm showing a list of books in the appropriate Book View:

```
@model IEnumerable<FirstTry.Models.Book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<p style="padding-left: 15px">
    @Html.ActionLink("Create a new book", "Create")
</p>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p style="padding-left: 15px">
        @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}



<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-9 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
                @*FIX THIS*@
                <a href="~/Books/Details/11">
                    <img src="@item.Img" style="width:250px; height:250px">
                </a>
                <span>Title: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)<br />
                <span>Price: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)<br />
                <span>Published: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)<br />
                <span>Genre: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

However, when I try and use the same model to display the books on my _Layout.cshtml page, an exception is thrown:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

```
@model IEnumerable<FirstTry.Models.Book>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-9 col-md-6 col-lg-3 my-3">
                @*FIX THIS*@
                <a href="~/Books/Details/11">
                    <img src="@item.Img" style="width:250px; height:250px">
                </a>
                <span>Title: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)<br />
                <span>Price: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)<br />
                <span>Published: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Year)<br />
                <span>Genre: </span>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
            </div>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit

The line throwing the exception is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

in _Layout.cshtml

My controller:

```
     public ActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {

            var books = from b in db.Books
                        select b;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                books = books.Where(b => b.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }

            return View(books.ToList());
        }
```

Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: When you say you are showing books on _Layout.cshtml. How you are passing the model to layout?

Answer (score 1):

> you are passing your model instance to index page, which is why it
>   works fine there.
>
> But in case of layout page you are not passing anything, so it will
>   show a null reference exception, since it doesn't have any instance
>   passed to it.
>
> _layout.cshtml pages don't have a corresponding ActionResult from
>   where you can pass the model. so if you really need it there you have
>   to do your query in the view itself or pass it via session or
>   something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The model instance for each view matters. The case where it's working, the values are not null, while the case where it's showing a `NullReferenceException` is where the value of something is `null`.

I recommend you take a look at the local variables when it's hitting the null exception.

Since your model is a list and you're iterating over it, there's two places that could be null:

1. `Model` itself is null
2. An item in the `Model` list is null

Based on your updated code including the controller/route, it's not immediately clear what's going wrong. It doesn't look like either `books.ToList()` nor the items in `books` list are null.

So my guess is the issue is related to how you're passing the model to the `_Layout.cshtml` file. Where are you configuring `_Layout.cshtml`'s model?